# Convert import statements to web paths

Tags: javascript

I am currently experimenting with Web Components. For this I installed a package with npm, which uses lit-element (polymer) to bring bootstrap to web components.

There you should always include only the components you need:

```
// e.g import only bs-alert
import 'lit-element-bootstrap/components/alert/bs-alert';

// e.g import all alert components
import 'lit-element-bootstrap/components/alert';

// e.g import all components (should be avoided)
import 'lit-element-bootstrap';
```

My question now is: How can I use these import statements directly in my web browser? Therefore the import statements have to be converted into real web paths. So I need a tool that goes through all these dependencies and rewrites their import statements to web paths.

I found a tool that does that, but it builds everything of 'lit-element-bootstrap' and I end up with a single 500+ KB file:
https://github.com/pikapkg/web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the long run, this should be solved by [import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps). This will basically allow the browser to know that `import 'lit-element-bootstrap/` actually means `import 'path/to/lit-element-bootstrap/`.

For now, you will need either a server that automatically changes the paths (like [polymer serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polymer-cli) or [owc-dev-server](https://open-wc.org/developing/owc-dev-server.html) or you need to apply a [build step](https://open-wc.org/building/).